# Is it possible to use absolute input device like a pointer or VR headset for peeking(looking) in non VR FPS or 3rd person games?

Tags: game-mechanics, input, virtual-reality, controllers

Assume I have a VR headset, which has absolute orientation as output and this orientation is input to a game.

In VR Games, your character looks wherever you look by using your headset's absolute orientation(right?) Everything is OK for VR games

Coming to the point for non VR games;

Normally, when you tilt a joystick to a direction and hold it at that position, your character always turns relative to the direction until you released your finger. For example if you tilt the joystick to rightest and hold it at there, your character starts rotationg around itself to the right until you release joystick.

Can I do the VR rotating thing with a standart game controller joystick? Do games (or game engines) allow this type of control? I mean when I tilt my stick to rightest position, my character peeks to rightest, but when I release the stick, character peeks to default(front).  If it is possible, could you give name of games that suppport this control type? What is the technical name for this control type and maybe some resources or keywords for my research?

Comment: Hi Yunus Yurtturk, and welcome to GameDev.StackExchange. We're here to help game developers solve problems in making their own new games or game mods. If this is a control scheme you're trying to incorporate into your own game or mod, we can help you solve design and technical implementation problems. But if you're interested in *playing* games of this style or simply *listing* existing games with this feature, those questions are not on-topic for this site.[You might want to consider asking on our game-playing sister site Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com) instead.

Comment: Hi; I'm not interested in gameplay. I'm looking for existing methods for the control scheme. Similar to https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/55233/how-to-map-absolute-joystick-position-to-object-rotation  on this network and https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/116004/what-the-difference-between-relative-and-absolute-input-mouse-vs-joystick on gaming network.  I feel this network is more suitable for my question, but of course my question is a little abstract

Comment: Note that the first question you link asks "How" to do something. That is absolutely something we can answer here, if you'd like to edit your question to ask that. Be sure to include information on what technology/engine/language you're using, and how you're trying to control your orientation so far.

Comment: It's really not clear what you're asking. The title sounds like you want to control a non-VR game using a VR headset. The last paragraph makes it sound like you want to control aiming in VR using a joystick.

Comment: Yep its a little bit confusing, combination of 3-4 concepts. I want a standart FPS game, to be controlled by a VR headset(yaw-pitch), in absolute input way. I say absolute because by using VR headset as relative input(mimicing mouse or joystic), errors accumulate and with a few head movements, headsets and game characters orientations get away from each other. I can overcome this problem if pc fps games support absolute input control type. Mouse and joystic are relative inputs by the way, they move our character by "difference" of movement they faced